# R. plotly - padding or margin for graph inside Shinyapp?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I've a plotly plot that has not right left margin (neither at the bottom). Cannot find the documentation to add this extra space so my y axis (this plot is in horinzontal mode) don't get cut.

**ui.R:**

```
tabItem(tabName = "ga",        
            column(12, offset = 2,
            plotlyOutput("plot")
            )         
    )
```

**server.R:**

```
  sesiones_por_fuente <- reactive({ 


    sesiones_ga <- read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2ggnb0p4mz2nus/sesiones-2018.csv?dl=1", skip = 0)

    sesiones_ga <- sesiones_ga %>%
                  group_by(sources) %>%
                  summarise(sessions = sum(sessions))


  })



  m <- list(
    l = 200,
    r = 50,
    b = 100,
    t = 100,
    pad = 20
  )


  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(sesiones_por_fuente(), x = ~sessions, y = ~sources, type = 'bar',
            width = 1200, height = 600, margin = m, orientation = 'h', pad=4) %>% 
      layout(title = "Sesiones por mes",
             xaxis = list(title = ""),
             yaxis = list(title = "")) %>%
      layout(hovermode = 'compare',
             separators = ',') 
  })
```

**data set:**

You can download the data with:

```
sesiones_por_fuente <- read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2ggnb0p4mz2nus/sesiones-2018.csv?dl=1", skip = 0)
```

or using recreate it with dput function:

```
sesiones_por_fuente <- structure(list(sources = c("adwords", "ccl", "criteo", "directo", 
"email", "facebookads", "onesignal", "organico", "redes sociales", 
"referencias", "rpp", "spam"), sessions = c(4534932L, 265532L, 
3959787L, 4290376L, 3870548L, 3125880L, 2345860L, 7002943L, 75382L, 
15061160L, 222730L, 5971162L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .Names = c("sources", "sessions"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = structure(list(date = structure(list(format = ""), .Names = "format", class = c("collector_date", 
    "collector")), hour = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), deviceCategory = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), source = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), medium = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), sessions = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), month = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), sources = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("date", "hour", "deviceCategory", 
    "source", "medium", "sessions", "year", "month", "sources"
    )), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

[image]

Comment: In order to make your question reproducible, you should define the `sesiones_por_fuente` function or better, provide a minimal data set to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @steveb don't think is necessary, as the graph can be achieve with any dataset. I just need to know how to add the extra padding when using horizontal orientation.

Comment: In general, you will get answers faster if you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @OmarGonzales You could yourself otherwise post with an inbuilt dataset of R so that we can use your code to support. Now in this case, someone has to write a new code using a new dataset.

Comment: @amrrs added data sample. thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given your `dput` data, you need to do two things, one which addresses your issue and one which will get rid of a warning:

- move `margin = m` from the call to `plot_ly` to the `layout` call as in the code below.
- Remove the `pad=4` option from the call to `plot_ly` as this gives a warning (i.e. it is an invalid option for `plot_ly`)

This is mainly an issue with how you are using `plot_ly`, not a shiny issue. I was able to reproduce the issue just using `plot_ly` in R, and the code below fixed the issue.

```
plot_ly(sesiones_por_fuente, x = ~sessions, y = ~sources, type = 'bar',
        width = 1200, height = 600, orientation = 'h') %>% 
  layout(title = "Sesiones por mes",
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title = ""),
         margin = m) %>%
  layout(hovermode = 'compare',
         separators = ',')
```

Here is the resulting plot with the extra space in the margin

[image: Plotly Plot with expanded margin for y-axis]

Answer (score 1):

I have two possible suggestions:

1) increase `l` from 200 to more. But as I saw, your words by plot space and this do not help;

2) increase `pad` to 100. But plot looks not good.

You have two `pads` with different size, maybe this cause the problem you stuck with