# R Shiny plotly horizontal legend doesnt fit properly when box is small

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Normally the legend of a plotly plot is positioned right to the plot. When added to a box in Shiny its scales well with the legend, no matter how small the box is...however when the legend is placed horizontally, the legend covers the plot when the box is scaled too small. Why is this? And how can I fox this?

Code plot:

```
x1 <- rnorm(50)
x2 <- rnorm(10)

fig <- plot_ly() 

fig <- fig %>% 
  
  add_histogram(x = ~x1, name = "X1", marker = list(color = "red")
  ) %>%
  
  add_histogram(x = ~x2, name = "X2", marker = list(color ="#blue")
  ) %>%
  
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h",
                       traceorder= 'normal',
                       xanchor = "center",
                       x = 0.5)
  )
```

Code Shiny app:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody(
                      box(
                        title = "test", 
                        width = 4, 
                        height = "auto", 
                        plotlyOutput("plot1", height = "360px"), 
                        inline = F
                      )
                    ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    fig
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268601/r-plotly-padding-or-margin-for-graph-inside-shinyapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a combination of the `margin` parameter of `plotly`'s `layout`, and the `y` parameter of the `legend` to generate the output below.

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)

x1 <- rnorm(50)
x2 <- rnorm(10)

# THIS CHANGE
m <- list(
  l = 10,
  r = 10,
  b = 100,
  t = 10,
  pad = 20
)

fig <- plot_ly() 

fig <- fig %>% 
  
  add_histogram(x = ~x1, name = "X1", marker = list(color = "red")
  ) %>%
  
  add_histogram(x = ~x2, name = "X2", marker = list(color ="#blue")
  ) %>%
  
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h",
                       traceorder= 'normal',
                       xanchor = "center",
                       x = 0.5,
                       y = -0.3), # THIS CHANGE
         margin = m # THIS CHANGE
  )


ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody(
                      box(
                        title = "test", 
                        width = 4, 
                        height = "auto", 
                        plotlyOutput("plot1", height = "360px"), 
                        inline = F
                      )
                    ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    fig
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thx, yes I tried the y = -0.3 but was wondering wether there was a another posibility..and also the padding part though when I checked it it wasnt entirely clear how it worked, but thx!

Comment: Do you need something different for a specific reason? Upvote if useful pls ;)

Comment: Well I have 2 dashboards: 1 dashboard with smaller plots in smaller boxes....and 1 full size plots in full width boxes. However with y = -0.3 the legend is placed to far below in the full width boxes...and so I was looking for 1 generic solution

Comment: I'll have a look, but if you have an example of this issue it might help

Comment: If you increase the width of the box to 12 with proper height than the legend will be placed to far unedrneath the x-axes with y=-0.3

Comment: Hi! Any idea yet? Or is this just a bug with plotly and the workaround is to work with y=-0.3? Its doable but it feels a bit strange tha plotly behaves like this...I would say that the legend is part of plot-area....just like when its added to the right

Comment: It seems like this issue is still open and is spread across the various plotly languages (python, js, R...) https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1199
It feels like there might be a way to fix this programmatically rather than manually but I would imagine that would need to be in JS (plotl'y native lang).